# Is there a phrase/proverb/idiom to describe selecting the right set of tools and methods to solve a problem

Tags: phrase-requests

or you have to select the right set of tools and method in order to solve the problem optimally.

or you have the insight/ability to identify/select the right set of tools and method to solve a problem.

Comment: 'Don't use a hammer when you need a screwdriver' is known and transparent but not really fully idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

As it happened I was looking for similar phrase and feel ["Horses for Courses"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/horses+for+courses) can probably fit in here.

Answer (score -2):

**tool up** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tool) an idiom

> 1. To become equipped with the tools, instruments, or machinery necessary for a task or one's job.

As in:

Now that I'm all **tooled up**, I can finally get to work repairing this fence.

Comment: Thanks. I am hoping to emphasise the ability to select or the selection process.